# .fill on layer gives an Error 24: .fill is not a function

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

Hello I am writing a script that changes layer colors in photoshop [the layers are circled in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Issc.png)

the layer type is NORMAL and my code is the following ...

```
function setClass2HexColor(){
   var doc= app.activeDocument;
   var colorGroup = doc.layerSets.getByName('COLORGROUP');
   var class2hex = colorGroup.layers.getByName('CLASS2HEX');
   var color = '7f7f7f7f'
   alert(color2hex.kind) // LayerKind.Normal
   class2hex.fill(color)
}
```

For some reason it says that class2hex.fill is not a function , Error 24...
I would appreciate any advice on the matter...

I know that there is also a way to accomplish the same task with scriptListener... how would that be done ?

Comment: Do you want to fill the layer contents with color? At the moment I do not see any layer named "color2hex" within the group.

Comment: @GrzegorzG. sorry that was a type on my part when i was writing the code in the question above. 
The names are correct in the real script.

Comment: Just going out on a limb here. Try making the color2hex layer active, make the foreground color the same as color and then fill with an RGB colour (not sure if you can do that with RGBa) . Check the docs - look at [working with art layers](http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/ps_doc_model.htm) section For script listener - you have to move it into the correct directory. [page 73 the scriptlistener plugin](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2015.pdf)